# ONSException Exception - no nodes configured

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle-manageddataaccess

When opening an Oracle Connection, I see a few Exceptions in output window.

```
Exception occurred: "OracleInternal.NotificationServices.ONSException" in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll
```

I updated the Oracle Management Driver to the latest Version, but still get it.

I did not configure any Load Balancing or ONS Service on the machine. The tracelog showed the following exception:

```
2019-09-10 10:47:12.500352 TID:5   (PRI) (SVC) (ERR) OracleONSNotificationManager.RegisterForNotification() (txnid=n/a) OracleInternal.NotificationServices.ONSException: ONS: No node lists were configured
   bei OracleInternal.NotificationServices.ONS..ctor(String config)
   bei OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleONSNotificationManager.RegisterForNotification(String serviceName, String databaseName, Int32 timeout, String eventTypeFromDb, String onsConfigFromDb)
```

The error will be thrown when I open the Connection like that:

```
Connection = new OracleConnection(cnString + $";Password={passwordDecryptedSecureString.SecureStringToString()}");
Connection.OpenAsync();
```

Did someone have the same issue? Or a solution maybe?

Best regards

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this?

Comment: Bump, if you did not saw the answer. I left the company I was working for this over a year ago, so I forgot about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of the exceptions, you need to explicitly turn off HA and Load Balancing.   Add `;HA EVENTS=false;LOAD BALANCING=false` to your connection string.